# What is "Code" in Linux Kernel crash messages?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, crash

I have the following stack trace and crash information after the Linux kernel failed to load:

```
[    3.684670] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    3.695507] Bad FPU state detected at fpu__clear+0x91/0xc2, reinitializing FPU registers.
[    3.695508] traps: No user code available.
[    3.704745] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT
[    3.715304] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.19.50-android-x86-geeb7e76-dirty #1
[    3.724594] Hardware name: AAEON UP-APL01/UP-APL01, BIOS UPA1AM21 09/01/2017
[    3.732622] EIP: ex_handler_fprestore+0x2e/0x65
[    3.737807] Code: 00 55 89 e5 57 8b 48 04 8d 44 08 04 89 42 30 80 3d e7 fb a0 c1 00 75 16 c6 05 e7 fb a0 c1 01 50 68 b4 38 87 c1 e8 98 ba 00 00 <0f> 0b 58 5a 90 8d 74 26 00 eb f
[    3.759027] EAX: 0000004d EBX: c103d6f9 ECX: c19a2a48 EDX: c19a2a48
[    3.766169] ESI: df4c7e04 EDI: 00000006 EBP: df4c7c6c ESP: df4c7c60
[    3.773316] DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068 EFLAGS: 00010292
[    3.781044] CR0: 80050033 CR2: c168c6b4 CR3: 1e902000 CR4: 001406d0
[    3.788184] Call Trace:
[    3.791026]  ? fpu__clear+0x91/0xc2
[    3.795037]  fixup_exception+0x61/0x6e
[    3.799348]  do_trap+0x35/0xe9
[    3.802864]  do_invalid_op+0xd9f/0x108a
[    3.807269]  ? atime_needs_update+0x68/0xf5
[    3.812058]  ? touch_atime+0x37/0xbd
[    3.816168]  ? __check_object_size+0x83/0x123
[    3.821153]  ? fpu__clear+0x8e/0xc2
[    3.825166]  ? generic_file_read_iter+0x28d/0x723
[    3.830544]  ? generic_file_read_iter+0x28d/0x723
[    3.835931]  ? __vfs_read+0xe9/0x11f
[    3.840043]  common_exception+0x105/0x10e
[    3.844634] EIP: fpu__clear+0x91/0xc2
[    3.848840] Code: eb 05 e8 b4 f2 fd ff ff 0d 98 a8 99 c1 74 3b 90 8d 74 26 00 eb 07 90 8d 74 26 00 eb 1c 83 c8 ff bf c0 8c a2 c1 89 c2 0f c7 1f <a1> f4 8b a2 c1 ff 0d 98 a8 99 1
[    3.870070] EAX: ffffffff EBX: df4c5900 ECX: 00000000 EDX: ffffffff
[    3.877210] ESI: df4c5900 EDI: c1a28cc0 EBP: df4c7e4c ESP: df4c7e40
[    3.884356] DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068 EFLAGS: 00010286
[    3.892085]  ? do_alignment_check+0x1a/0x1a
[    3.896878]  ? common_exception+0x105/0x10e
[    3.901674]  flush_thread+0x33/0x37
[    3.905684]  flush_old_exec+0x540/0x5f9
[    3.910085]  load_elf_binary+0x24b/0xec1
[    3.914584]  ? pick_next_task_fair+0xdf/0x13a
[    3.919575]  ? __schedule+0x4bb/0x63f
[    3.923780]  ? sched_debug_header+0x45/0x40a
[    3.928666]  ? preempt_schedule+0x2d/0x3c
[    3.933266]  search_binary_handler+0x89/0x1ac
[    3.938259]  load_script+0x184/0x19f
[    3.942366]  search_binary_handler+0x89/0x1ac
[    3.947354]  __do_execve_file+0x454/0x668
[    3.951954]  do_execve+0x1b/0x1d
[    3.955673]  run_init_process+0x31/0x36
[    3.960082]  ? rest_init+0x99/0x99
[    3.963992]  kernel_init+0x5e/0xdf
[    3.967905]  ret_from_fork+0x19/0x30
[    3.972014] Modules linked in:
[    3.975542] ---[ end trace 7d27fceeb3852a38 ]---
[    3.980823] EIP: ex_handler_fprestore+0x2e/0x65
[    3.986014] Code: 00 55 89 e5 57 8b 48 04 8d 44 08 04 89 42 30 80 3d e7 fb a0 c1 00 75 16 c6 05 e7 fb a0 c1 01 50 68 b4 38 87 c1 e8 98 ba 00 00 <0f> 0b 58 5a 90 8d 74 26 00 eb f
[    4.007247] EAX: 0000004d EBX: c103d6f9 ECX: c19a2a48 EDX: c19a2a48
[    4.014387] ESI: df4c7e04 EDI: 00000006 EBP: df4c7c6c ESP: c1afa3b0
[    4.021536] DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068 EFLAGS: 00010292
[    4.029265] CR0: 80050033 CR2: c168c6b4 CR3: 1e902000 CR4: 001406d0
[    4.036413] note: swapper[1] exited with preempt_count 1
```

What does the `Code` mean? Also can I know the exact x86 instruction (not the C function) that caused the kernel to crash?

**EDIT:** Updated the code. I was trying to run Linux in a virtualized environment.

Comment: The instruction `<0f> 0b` is the instruction that causes the exception. That is the `UD2` instruction. That usually indicates the code shouldn't have reached that position (some kind of undefined behavior detected maybe? It may well be that `call` instruction just before it (bytes e8 98 ba 00 00) wasn't meant to return but it did. Without seeing that function it is hard to tell.

Comment: Do you happen to be running this in an emulator (like KVM/QEMU)?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, we are running in a virtualized environment. I have updated the original post. So, may be, something else is causing this illegal instruction.

Comment: No, clearly it's still running `0f 0b   ud2` that's causing the illegal-instruction exception.  That's the sole purpose of `ud2`.  A virtualized environment just makes it easier to attach a debugger to the VM and investigate after a crash, or set a breakpoint earlier.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I actually asked about the virtualized environment because there are some known FPU related bugs on some versions of Linux and some virtual machines (including KVM). I suspect that may be related to the issue of the actual crash. I didn't ask about a virtualized environment from a debugging standpoint. I had a suspicion that ultimately this might be an XY problem which it may be since the OP suggests in a comment _I initially did not understand why Linux was crashing._

Comment: Read my comments to the Peter’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Code` is a hexdump of x86 machine code** (presumably 32-bit mode from a legacy 32-bit kernel since it only dumped 32-bit register contents).

**The byte marked with `<>` is where EIP is pointing**, so it's the faulting instruction inside `ex_handler_fprestore`

**Feed it to a disassembler, e.g. https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2**, or Linux's crashdump decoding script https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/decodecode

---

Remember that x86 machine code uses a variable-length encoding that can't be unambiguously decoded backwards.  But this is compiler-generated code, so at least we can assume there aren't supposed to be overlapping instructions or static data mixed with code (because x86 has no benefit for that).  If we find the start of a function in compiler-generated code, the rest of the instructions will all be "sane".

The `00` byte looks like part of a previous instruction or padding between functions:  Decoding from there would give us `add    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x77],dl` which is plausible, `in eax,0x57` after that isn't, for a non-driver function.

Much more likely is that the `0x89` byte is the opcode of a MOV instruction.

**If we drop the `00` byte and start from `55` (which is `push ebp`), we get a normal function body** including the stack-frame setup prologue you'd expect if compiled with `-Os` or `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

In general, you can drop bytes one at a time until you get a sane-looking decoding that at least has an instruction-boundary on the faulting instruction.  (But some experience is required for "sane-looking"; disassembly may have gotten in sync by chance after starting wrong.  That's not rare for x86 machine code.)

```
# skipped the 00 byte which would desync decoding
0:  55                      push   ebp
1:  89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
3:  57                      push   edi
4:  8b 48 04                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [eax+0x4]      # EAX = 1st function arg, ECX = tmp
7:  8d 44 08 04             lea    eax,[eax+ecx*1+0x4]
b:  89 42 30                mov    DWORD PTR [edx+0x30],eax     # EDX = 2rd function arg
e:  80 3d e7 fb a0 c1 00    cmp    BYTE PTR ds:0xc1a0fbe7,0x0
15: 75 16                   jne    0x2d
17: c6 05 e7 fb a0 c1 01    mov    BYTE PTR ds:0xc1a0fbe7,0x1
1e: 50                      push   eax
1f: 68 b4 38 87 c1          push   0xc18738b4
24: e8 98 ba 00 00          call   0xbac1
29: 0f 0b                   ud2                     ### <=== EIP points here

# stuff after this probably isn't real code; it's unreachable
2b: 58                      pop    eax
2c: 5a                      pop    edx
2d: 90                      nop
2e: 8d 74 26 00             lea    esi,[esi+eiz*1+0x0]
32: eb                      .byte 0xeb
```

So this function really ends with a call to a `noreturn` function with stack args.  (32-bit x86 Linux kernels are built with `-mregparm=3` so the first 3 args are in EAX, EDX, ECX in that order, so either this function is not regparm or it has more than 3 args.  You can see this function uses EAX and EDX as incoming args: reading them before writing.)

But it's not a `jmp` tailcall for some reason; maybe for exception backtracing it wants this function's stack frame on the stack.  (Which might explain the `push ebp` / `mov ebp,esp` even if this kernel was built with `-fomit-frame-pointer` as part of `-O2`.)

You'd have to look at the C source for `ex_handler_fprestore` to guess why that might be.

[`ud2` is an illegal instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud).  The compiler (or inline asm?) put it there so it would fault if the function returned.  It's a clear sign that this path of execution is supposed to be unreachable, or is marked to intentionally trap as an `assert()` type of mechanism.  (In Linux, **look for `BUG_ON()`**).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your explanation. It helped me understand how we should go about finding the bad instruction. I have updated the original post as I initially did not understand why Linux was crashing.

Comment: Why not to use simple `decodecode` script from kernel source tree?

Comment: @0andriy: thanks, good suggestion.  I don't usually debug kernel crash dumps so I just kind of approached this question out of curiosity, not with experience with existing tools beyond baseline assemblers / disassembers.

Comment: Ah, and forgot to mention that `ud2` in 99.9% cases means *look for `BUG_ON()`* in the code.

Comment: @0andriy: thanks, wasn't sure if `BUG_ON()` jumped to more detailed error-reporting or if it was just a `ud2`.  Also note that if you compile with clang, or some modern GCC versions, some kinds of C undefined behaviour can get compiled to `ud2` (instead of doing normal code-gen for a path of execution through a function that always leads to some kind of UB that the compiler doesn't want to handle.)

Comment: Yes, that's why I avoided 100% probability :-)

Comment: It turned out that `XSAVES`/`XRSTORS` was causing the `UD` exception because the virtualization environment did not support those features. Thanks for your help!